# C# Disable/Enable Button based on Empty/Populated Text Boxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form with 5 text boxes and a button, and when the button is clicked it send the data to a SQL database. I would like the button to be disabled if any of the text boxes are null, how do I do this in C#? (I am in Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET web app)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write JavaScript/jQuery code.

Comment: Write conditions in jQuery and use this method to disable the button, $("#<%=button1.ClientID>%>").attr("disabled", "disabled");. To enable buttton, use this code, $("#<%=button1.ClientID>%>").removeAttr("disabled");

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use Client side scripts, you can use `validations` for your controls

`<asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" runat="server" />
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator1"

  runat="server" ErrorMessage="Required!" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" >
 </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`

Validation will trigger on postbacks.

If you have multiple controls, but you do not want to validate them all, you can use `Validation Group`. Check this link for using [Validation Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx)

Comment: Be sure to set the property `EnableClientScript="true"` otherwise the buttons will never become enabled as the text fields get filled.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, What Sam said is right!!
you need  to check first whether all your text boxes are empty or not.
that will be done by

```
If(txtbox1.text == "" || txtbox2.text == "" || txtbox3.text == "" || txtbox4.text == "" || txtbox5.text == "")
```

If any of the text box is empty then make the button disabled.

```
  button1.enable = false;
```

If all are filled then make it as enabled.

```
  button1.enable = true;
```

Comment: Alright, this works,  but how do I get the button to be enabled as soon as the user starts typing in the box?

Comment: keep onkeypress event in that,i mean onkeypress event of that textbox make the button as enable

Answer (score 0):

use javascript setInterval on Page load if if you are using this single form on the page  and check each textbox value length .. if anyone is null then disable submit button..

use jquery to disable and enable them..  check following code snippet that i have created for sample..

use this to access server control id if you are using these controls inside some container control eg. panel, contentplaceholder etc :  `$("#<%=button1.ClientID>%>")`

`$("#text1").val().length` will check then length of text in textbox.. and then use jquery to enable and disable them..

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <%-- <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
    <%--<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>--%>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            $("#text1").keypress(function () {
                check();
            });

            var intv = self.setInterval("check()", 1000);

        });

        function check() {
            if ($("#text1").val().length > 0) {

                $("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
            }
            else {

                $("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="text1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```